# Armature going crazy

Tags: armature

Today i was doing some texture painting, and when i saved and closed blender everything seemed fine, but when i opened the blend file later, the body mesh was completely off.[image]

The body was in a different location, alot higher, is even a bit smaller, and two of the fingers are horribly stretched out. Together with this all were broken, and if i tried to fix this by relocating the mesh to the position of the armature all the animations stop working at all.

In the image there is the body i was working on (female), and the armature of the female body in the middle (both were at the position where the male body is)
The male body didnt change location or size randomly, but just got his fingers stretched.

How can i fix this? i have no idea how this happened, and i cant seem to find a solution that does not involve losing ALOT of progress by reloading a backup.

Comment: I think you should upload your file

Comment: You need not worry about the particular thumb issue.  You can fix all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup you latest defective file and work with a copy.

The armature modifier can be deleted and then a second bind to armature can be performed.

Deleting an armature modifier may sound error prone.  Yet Blender features can be deleted and recreated.

If you saved the binding position for example in Frame 1 then you can simply bind a second time.

It is unfortunate that you had this location of mesh accident.  There are many ways this can happen. One is moving the keyframed mesh and NOT setting a location keyframe. Keyframe mesh position in frame 1.

You may choose to move your mesh to the origin.  Place the armature and bind to armature correctly.  Frame 1.

You may consider in the future that you may rebind at any time in Frame 1.

Comment: Thanks, i sort of used what you said and made it work!!!